# Display data from sql database to a textbox

Tags: php, sql, textbox

I am performing a search of my sql database, and assigning the data from each row to a variable. Ex.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `sitestreet` LIKE  '$street'");
// display query results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $sitestreet = $row['sitestreet'];
        $sitestate =$row['sitestate'];                           
    }
```

Now my question is how do I get that info to display as text in a text box?

Thanks!

Comment: note that if your not using left/right wild cards on the like statement like '%$street%' you may as well use where `sitestreet` = '$street'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
<input value='<?php echo $sitestreet; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 2):

By echoing a textbox with those variables in the `value=""` attribute

```
echo "<input type='text' id='sitestreet' value='$sitestreet' />"
echo "<input type='text' id='sitestate' value='$sitestate' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch and assign in some time:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      echo "<input type='text' id='sitestreet' value='$row['sitestreet']' /><br />
            <input type='text' id='sitestate' value='$row['sitestate']' />";                      
    }
```